# How to get same numerator value on dividing by zero in Webdatarocks table

Tags: javascript, webdatarocks

I want to get same numerator value when Denominator is zero in Webdatrocks table.
In documentation they have mentioned function "**divideByZeroValue**", but it can hold only **static** value.

https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/number-formatting/

Please assist is there any way to do so.

Comment: Example : Like if 5/0 = 5

Answer (score 0):

I suppose "**divideByZeroValue**" does not work for your case. It just allows setting an appropriate alias for the division by zero representation.

It seems that writing an if() formula should solve your case. For example, if you write the following formula `if( count("Color") ==  0, sum("Price") , sum("Price")/count("Color"))` you will avoid division by zero cases.